# Export Distribution Group

Tags: powershell, office365

I need to export the following to a `csv` or `excel` file

```
-Distribution Group (PrimarySmtpAddress)
-Distribution Group members and each primarysmtpaddress
```

I tried adding

```
Group email: $($group) | PrimarySmtpAddress
```

in the code below but it does not add it.

```
#This is what works but is missing
$groups = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited | Select -ExpandProperty name

ForEach ($group in $groups) 
{
"Group Name: $($group)`nGroup Members:`n"

Get-DistributionGroupMember $group |ft name,alias,primarysmtpaddress 

}
```

I am missing the Distribution group primary smtp address?

Comment: is the `.Name` of the DG the same as the primary address? if not, then you stripped it out when you used Select-Object and chose only one property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) commented, you are stripping out all properties except the `Name` by doing `Select -ExpandProperty name`. Next, if you want to export to a CSV file, DO NOT USE `Format-Table` (`ft`), because that is only to format the result to the console.

What you should do is create an array of objects and pipe that to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet, like in the below (untested) code:

```
$outputFile = '<PATH AND FILENAME FOR THE EXPORTED CSV FILE>'

Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object {
    # The Identity parameter for Get-DistributionGroupMember specifies the distribution group
    # or mail-enabled security group. You can use any value that uniquely identifies the group.
    # The cmdlet also accepts the Identity parameter as pipeline input, so 
    # $_ | Get-DistributionGroupMember will also work.
    $Members = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $($_.PrimarySmtpAddress) 
    foreach ($member in $Members) { 
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            GroupName   = $_.DisplayName
            GroupAlias  = $_.Alias
            GroupEmail  = $_.PrimarySMTPAddress
            MemberName  = $member.DisplayName
            MemberEmail = $member.PrimarySMTPAddress
            # Maybe also add RecipientType to distinguish between users and groups?
            # MemberType  = $member.RecipientType
        }
    } 
} | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I will give a try tomorrow. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Great news. It did work and was able to output everything needed.

Comment: How would I insert another criteria for last email received?

Get-MessageTrackingLog -EventId Receive